# Gazebo sensor plugin accuracy of realsense T265

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, ros-noetic, realsense

I'm planning to do research about realsense T265 on Gazebo simulation. How can I know the accuracy of this sensor. I'm Using this https://github.com/nilseuropa/realsense_ros_gazebo repository. or how should I tell about this sensor model in the research?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking about. Do you want to know the accuracy of the real device, or do you want to know how well the gazebo model matches the behavior of the real device? Which version of gazebo are you using?

Comment: I want to know how well the gazebo model matches the behavior of the real device. Not sure abt gazebo version, I am using ros1 noetic, i guess it is gazebo 11?

Comment: What use case are you evaluating? Do you want to move to a real device in the future?